# The Laurent series expansion of 1/((z^2)(z+1))

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

In an example in our notes it says: Compute the Laurent series for $f(z)= \frac{1}{z^2(z+1)}$  and determine the annulus of convergence.

No more information was provided. So I did it on my own by factoring it into $\left( \frac{1}{z^2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{z(1-(-(1/z)))} \right)$ then using geometric series to get an expression where it's convergent for $|z| > 1$. I looked back at the notes to check my answer and saw the way he obtained the solution was by factoring it into $\left( \frac{1}{z^2} \right)(1-(-z))$ and getting an expression where it was convergent for all $|z| < 1$. Would they both be considered correct answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Laurent series would have two different representations in two different sectors: |z| < 1 and |z| > 1. Since you make the decomposition into series around zero, and you have a pole in zero, you will always have negative terms. If you took, for exemple, $$\frac{1}{(z - 1)(z - 2)},$$ you would have 3 different decompositions: one for |z| < 1, which is just a Tailor series (with n=0 to infinity), one for $1 < |z| < 2$ (both negative and positive degrees) and one for $|z| > 2$ (as far as I remember, this one contains only the negative degrees of z).

In your case, the Taylor series "shrink" to an empty circle with radius 0 because of the pole in zero.

So, both of your solutions are correct, but for different regions.

BTW, when you say $|z| < 1$, you should state that $z\neq 0$: $0< |z| < 1$

Comment: Oh ok, that was my line of reasoning as well. However if I was given that question on exam (like the one I have in 5 hours) would it be correct to list only one region (as we both did), or would I have to state both regions? Also if it doesn't say which pole to expand around do I just assume 0?

Comment: For the first part: yes, you have to make both expansions and mention both regions. BUT: if you read your task literally, it asks you for annulus, but $|z| > 1$ is not an anulus. $0 < |z| < 1$ is. For the secont part, yes you have to know wich point you want to use as the "center" of the decomposition. BUT: this point is any point, not only the pole. You can make a decomposition at $z = 5$ and your radius for the first decomposition will be 5-1=4. Try drawing the circles centerd at 5 that pass through your poles and you'll see.

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes sense.